# Angularjs chosen exception with jquery-chosen 1.8.7 and angularjs 1.8.0

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen, angular-chosen

My project has some libraries

- angularjs.1.8.x
- jquery.3.5.1
- jquery-chosen.1.8.7
- angular-chosen.1.9.2 (angularjs)

that works fine. I want update angular-chosen to 1.9.3 but it is gettting exception (just load page):
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] etc 
(element that is triggering it is jquery-3.5.1 as I can see in stacktrace and I must use this version of jquery, so solution can't be to use previous version of jquery)
I haven't seen anything about how solve that error 'googling'

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Version installed via npm was lower than 1.9.2 and can be installed with 'npm install angular-chosen'. However it is not desirable version so type 'npm install angular-chosen-localytics' to get last version of library as [suggests](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen) in github page